# change css3 border properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css

```
div
{
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
-moz-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
}
```

i want to cange the border image of my div tag using javascript dom

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').css({
  "border-image"           :  "url(border.png) 30 30 round",
  "-moz-border-image"      :  "url(border.png) 30 30 round",
  "-webkit-border-image"   :  "url(border.png) 30 30 round",
  "-o-border-image"        :  "url(border.png) 30 30 round"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to cange the border image of my div tag using javascript dom

You can do like:

```
var dv = document.getElementById('#divID');
dv.style.borderImage = 'url(border.png) 30 30 round';
dv.style.MozBorderImage = 'url(border.png) 30 30 round';
dv.style.WebkitBorderImage = 'url(border.png) 30 30 round';
dv.style.OBorderImage = 'url(border.png) 30 30 round';
```

If you want to do for all DIVs:

```
var dvs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < dvs.length; i++) {
    dvs[i].style.borderImage = 'url(border.png) 30 30 round';
    dvs[i].style.MozBorderImage = 'url(border.png) 30 30 round';
    dvs[i].style.WebkitBorderImage = 'url(border.png) 30 30 round';
    dvs[i].style.OBorderImage = 'url(border.png) 30 30 round';
}
```